# amcharts chart title is not showing

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am using amcharts to draw bar chart. I need a chart title in my chart.

So I put graph title my code as follows:

`graph.title="Beer chart";`

But title is not coming.

Check my fiddle : [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/santhucool007/baffygje/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You added a title for your graph. To add title to the whole chart, use [`titles`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#titles) array (for JSON-based config), or [`addTitle()`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#addTitle) method for object-based. (you seem to be using the latter).

I.e.:

```
chart.addTitle("Beer chart");
```

Here's your fiddle updated as per above:
http://jsfiddle.net/baffygje/1/